# angularjs v1 script not loading on page change

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a small issue in my project is that I am using routing for different pages. Page are changing fine butt not loading Java script when I go to another page. Kindly help me out. Also i want to page autoscroll top.

```
<div class="ng-view" autoscroll="true"></div>
```

routing code

```
adminapp.config( function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
 .when('/', {
    templateUrl: "frontend/views/home.html",
    controller: "common",
    css: "frontend/assets/css/style.css"
 }) 
 .when('/about', {
    templateUrl: "frontend/views/about.html",
    controller: "common",
    css: "frontend/assets/css/style.css"
 })
});
```

Comment: what do you mean by javascript ? where are the references?

Comment: For example: I used jquery flip on about page. when i go on about us page script(flip js) not load. When i do refresh page looks fine.

Comment: Hi @mohsin_uiux why don't you add all the *.js files in the index.html itself??

Comment: @alexis-toby already added in index.html. still not loading without refresh :(

Comment: @marcus-h cannot add on plunker because database are attached + large amount of files. so its difficult for me add on plunker.

Comment: @mohsin_uiux u can just mock the api response in the plunker.